# Laravel 7 API email verification is not updating email_verified_at

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, email-verification, laravel-mail

I'm trying to implement email verification after registration. Email is sent successfully and the link redirects to the login page but the email_verified_at is not updating

In routes/web.php

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

User.php:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use Notifiable;
use HasApiTokens;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','phone', 'brand_website', 'sms_code', 'sms_verified_at', 'fcm_token', 'email_verified_at',
];
```

The verification requires signing in and while using the API there's no sign in so it can't fetch the current user to compare the user id in the verification URL. How to fix this?

Comment: Is this useful to you ? https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Clément-Baconnier here's the answer https://medium.com/@pran.81/how-to-implement-laravels-must-verify-email-feature-in-the-api-registration-b531608ecb99